# Can I use UV project modifier for a specific face?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I just need the top face to use the UV Project modifier. How can I do it?

Comment: When UV Unwrapping you select your desired faces to unwrap.

Comment: @Lukaash They are using the 'UV project' modifier.

Comment: @RayMairlot Oh, i see, silly me.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do it with one material applied to all faces? Or can the single face have a separate material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to get a clean separation in texturing between the faces is to set up two materials, one for the single face, and one for the rest of the mesh. Then you can set up a UV map for each material and they won't conflict with each other due to the face assignment of the materials.

In my example, I'm actually UV projecting textures for both materials even though you don't need to do that. Just set up the UV projection for the top face in order to achieve the result you want.

[image]

**STEP ONE**

Create 2 UV Maps (you can unwrap the whole mesh into both maps, as we are differentiating between the textures via face material assignment)

[image]

**STEP TWO**

Create 2 Materials Similar to the screenshot

[image]
[image]

**STEP THREE**

Apply the materials to the desired faces in Edit mode.

[image]

**STEP FOUR**

Set up the UV Projection modifier like this (you can just do 1 projection even though I've done 2). You'll also need a separate camera for projection (you can use the main camera but it's generally more convenient to use a separate camera)

[image]

**STEP FIVE**

Now you should have a different material and a texture that is UV projection on your mesh surfaces.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this is enough detail to give you a solution. I can make the steps more explicit if need be.

Comment: Thank, Can i use UV Project only in blue rect faces? i try to make no texture deform in there and just one material. http://imgur.com/lpex5mV

Comment: Sure, just disable the UVProject Mod that is operating on the top texture. Then the top texture will be fixed by standard texture mapping, and the rest of the cube will use textures mapped via the UVProject mod.